# SBPLLatticePlanner and pose_follower

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I finally managed to set up [SBPLLatticePlanner](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl_lattice_planner) (as a Global Planner) and [pose_follower](http://wiki.ros.org/pose_follower?distro=groovy) (as a local planner) on my robot (ROS Hydro and Ubuntu 12.04).

However, the robot is always stuck and does not move, and after a while I get this message:

```
[ERROR] [1417330887.447088561]: Aborting because the robot appears to be oscillating over and over. Even after executing all recovery behaviors
```

I'm sure that [SBPLLatticePlanner](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl_lattice_planner) works fine, since the robot is moving to the goal when using [DWAPlannerROS](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner), so the issue is probably pose_follower.

My robot is non holonomic but can rotate in place.

Here's the yaml file I am using for pose_follower:

```
PoseFollower:
  k_trans: 2.0
  k_rot: 2.0
  tolerance_trans: 0.05
  tolerance_rot: 0.04
  tolerance_timeout: 0.5
  holonomic: false
  samples: 1
  max_vel_lin: 0.3
  min_vel_lin: 0.1
  max_vel_th: 0.1
  min_vel_th: 0.0
  min_in_place_vel_th: 0.2
  in_place_trans_vel: 0.05
  trans_stopped_velocity: 0.0001
  rot_stopped_velocity: 0.0001
```

Yaml file for DWAPlannerROS

```
DWAPlannerROS:

  max_vel_x: 0.3  # 0.55
  min_vel_x: 0.0 

  max_vel_y: 0.0  # diff drive robot
  min_vel_y: 0.0  # diff drive robot

  max_trans_vel: 0.2 # choose slightly less than the base's capability
  min_trans_vel: 0.1  # this is the min trans velocity when there is negligible rotational velocity
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.1

  # Warning!
  #   do not set min_trans_vel to 0.0 otherwise dwa will always think translational velocities
  #   are non-negligible and small in place rotational velocities will be created.

  max_rot_vel: 2.0  # choose slightly less than the base's capability
  min_rot_vel: 0.4  # this is the min angular velocity when there is negligible translational velocity
  rot_stopped_vel: 0.4
  
  acc_lim_x: 1.0 # maximum is theoretically 2.0, but we 
  acc_lim_theta: 2.0
  acc_lim_y: 0.0      # diff drive robot

# Goal Tolerance Parameters
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3  # 0.05
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15  # 0.10
  # latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

# Forward Simulation Parameters
  sim_time: 1.0       # 1.7
  vx_samples: 6       # 3
  vy_samples: 1       # diff drive robot, there is only one sample
  vtheta_samples: 20  # 20

# Trajectory Scoring Parameters
  path_distance_bias: 90.0      # 32.0   - weighting for how much it should stick to the global path plan
  goal_distance_bias: 24.0      # 24.0   - wighting for how much it should attempt to reach its goal
  occdist_scale: 0.50           # 0.01   - weighting for how much the controller should avoid obstacles
  forward_point_distance: 0.325 # 0.325  - how far along to place an additional scoring point
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2         # 0.2    - amount of time a robot must stop in before colliding for a valid traj.
  scaling_speed: 0.25           # 0.25   - absolute velocity at which to start scaling the robot's footprint
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2       # 0.2    - how much to scale the robot's footprint when at speed.

# Oscillation Prevention Parameters
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05  # 0.05   - how far to travel before resetting oscillation flags

# Debugging
  publish_traj_pc : true
  publish_cost_grid_pc: true
  global_frame_id: odom


# Differential-drive robot configuration - necessary?
#  holonomic_robot: false
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198586/sbpllatticeplanner-and-pose_follower/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you've set `samples: 1` for the pose_follower. You may want to increase that a bit.

You may also want to adjust the rotational velocity limits to be similar to the limits that you're using for DWAPlannerROS.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-12-01**:
Changing the parameters didn't fix the issue yet. The robot is sometimes rotating around itself, but does not move towards the goal.